# Jquery Dropdown Multiple Selection

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add a text in jquery dropdown when multiple selection option is set as false. Please let me know asap.

Note : My requirement is to add a text 'All' in the dropdown and also it should allow single selection only.

Thanks,
Saraswathi.T

Comment: Is it possible, yes, with some code.

Comment: *Our requirement* is that you include the relevant code.

Comment: This is not just a Disscussion forum,it would be better if you share your code and also read all the terms & conditions of StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want a dropdown in your HTML like so:

```
<select id="mSelect">
    <option value="foo">foo</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option
</select>
```

As long as you don't have `multiple` set when creating your select, it won't allow multiple selection.

And then your jQuery to add another option:

```
$('#mSelect').append('<option value="All">All</option>');
```